# How to query JSONB array using TypeORM and PostgreSQL

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have table named 'HistoryLog' (id: int4, data: jsonb) as below

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"action":"deleted","actionDetail":"removed user Ravi"},{"action":"refresh","actionDetail":"data refreshed by user Nate"}] |
| 2 | [{"action":"deleted","actionDetail":"removed user Ben"}] |

I need to query this table in typeORM to fetch the rows based on searchText

**Issue:
Below code searches only first object of jsonb array.
I need help to search in every object of the jsonb array and return the entire row if it contains given 'search text'**

My TypeORM Code:

```
this.createQueryBuilder('HistoryLog')
.select([HistoryLog.data as result])
.where(new Brackets((qb)=> {
  qb.where(`HistoryLog.data::jsonb -> 0 ->> 'action' ilike '%${searchText}%'`)
    .orWhere(`HistoryLog.data::jsonb -> 0 ->> 'actionDetail' ilike '%${searchText}%'`)
})).getRawMany();
```

Need help to update this query builder to fetch below desired result:

1> search text: Ben

| result |
| --- |
| [{"action":"deleted","actionDetail":"removed user Ben"}] |

2> search text: Ravi

| result |
| --- |
| [{"action":"deleted","actionDetail":"removed user Ravi"},{"action":"refresh","actionDetail":"data refreshed by user Nate"}] |

3> search text: remove

| result |
| --- |
| [{"action":"deleted","actionDetail":"removed user Ravi"},{"action":"refresh","actionDetail":"data refreshed by user Nate"}] |
| [{"action":"deleted","actionDetail":"removed user Ben"}] |